# How to use ternary operation while setting state in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to make an API call only when the entered value is different than the previous value in the textbox. I am trying to use ternary operator in below method which is throwing compilation error. Could someone please help me .

I already set serialNumber in state as "serialNumber"  : ""

```
updatePartSerialNumberDummy(){
        this.setState(
            {
                serialNumber: this.input.value
            }, () => {this.props.getPartSerialNumberDetails(this.props.serviceProviderId,this.props.serviceProviderLocationId, this.state.serialNumber);}
        )}
```

And once the api call is done i am setting serialnumber that is entered in props like this.props.serialNumber would give the serialNumber with which the api call has made. Now next time I want to call the API only when user enteres a different value.

Comment: Trying to add Something like this 
this.input.value === this.props.serialNumber  ? null :  this.setState(
            {
                serialNumber: this.input.value
            }, () => {this.props.getPartSerialNumberDetails(this.props.serviceProviderId,this.props.serviceProviderLocationId, this.state.serialNumber)})

Comment: `this.setState` returns nothing, just use a simple `if`?

Comment: where is the ternary operator you're trying to use?

Comment: In the first comment @Dupocas

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need a ternary operator in this case:

```
updatePartSerialNumberDummy(){
   if(this.input.value === this.props.serialNumber) return null
   this.setState(
            {
                serialNumber: this.input.value
            }, () => {this.props.getPartSerialNumberDetails(this.props.serviceProviderId,this.props.serviceProviderLocationId, this.state.serialNumber);}
        )}
}
```

But you could achieve it like this:

```
updateWithternaryOperator(){
    this.setState({
        value : input !== 2 ? null : input
    },() => input !== 2 ? null : doSomethingCaseValueIs2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing something like this.
Also added null/undefined check for this.input.value

```
updatePartSerialNumberDummy(){
   if(this.input.value && (this.input.value !== this.props.serialNumber)){
        this.setState(
            {
                serialNumber: this.input.value
            }, () => {this.props.getPartSerialNumberDetails(this.props.serviceProviderId,this.props.serviceProviderLocationId, this.state.serialNumber);}
        )}
}
```